# How do I import words from a text file?

Tags: python-import

[image]h

words_to_guess= (which code should I enter here in order to import words from a text file )

my text file is names word.txt so i tried

```
words_to_guess =import words.txt
```

Comment: Please do not post [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the content of a .txt file to a variable using this code:

```
words_to_guess = open("words.txt")
```

Just make sure that the file "words.txt" is in the same directory as the .py file (or if you're compiling it to a .exe, the same directory as the .exe file)

I would also like to point out that based on the screenshot you provided, it looks like you're trying to get a random word from the .txt file. Once you've done the above code, I would recommend adding this code below it as well:

```
words_to_guess = words_to_guess.split()
```

This will take the content of "words_to_guess" and split every word into a list that can be further accessed. You can then call:

```
word = random.choice(words_to_guess)
```

And it will select a random element from the array into the "word" variable, hence providing you a random word from the .txt file.

Just note that in the split() function, a word is determined by the spaces in between, so if you have a word like "Halloween Pumpkin" or "American Flag", the split() function would make each individual word an element, so it would be transferred into ["Halloween", "Pumpkin"] or ["American", "Flag"].

That's all!